# How to do this lower screen swipe registration page?

Tags: android, swipe

[image]

For the above link, please advise on how best to do the section of Female, Male, Business? Where with each swipe the free text field changes to others? Is there an "official" name for this kind of swipe, ie. like "actionbar"?

Thank you.

Comment: Please check the library ViewPagerIndicator http://viewpagerindicator.com/

Comment: You should probably go for fragments, a viewpager, and a PagerTabStrip or equivalent. Hope this helps. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for your replies. ha... I just realised, I need to do the top language tab as well. Top tab, then the below data and text changes with the bottom swipe box appearing.

Comment: Or even, instead of swipe, what about tab within a tab? And different languages get displayed.